# Cascading - cascading.tuple.TupleException: failed to set a value

Tags: java, cascading

I am trying to apply ScrubFunction on each tuple and return the tuple with updated values.

But i am getting the Exception like..

```
Caused by: cascading.tuple.TupleException: failed to set a value, tuple may not be initialized with values, is zero length
```

**Sample Code:**

```
TupleEntry argument = functionCall.getArguments();
        Tuple result = new Tuple();
        result.setInteger(0, argument.getInteger(0));
        result.setString(1, argument.getString(1).toUpperCase());
        result.setString(2, argument.getString(2));
        result.setString(3, argument.getString(3));
        result.setString(4, argument.getString(4));
        result.setString(5, argument.getString(5));
        functionCall.getOutputCollector().add(result);
```

What if i want to update few fields in a `Tuple` and return the updated values.

Can i update directly in `TupleEntry` and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your first question: don't set values to a tuple, instead, add.

```
Tuple result = new Tuple();
result.addInteger(argument.getInteger(0));
// ...
```

To your second question: yes. See the API doc here: [TupleEntry.setObject](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.2/javadoc/cascading/tuple/TupleEntry.html#setObject(java.lang.Comparable,%20java.lang.Object))

Hope this helps :)